# How to Add Sprite Object With Animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

What I'm about to ask might be completely nonsense/basic or something else. Because my AS knowledge is too little. Hope I can explain correctly

I am tring to create a sliding banner animation dynamically. The reason that I create dynamic is that I want to load banner images and headlines from XML file.

So I found a sample project with .as and .xml file. It does what I want but it has no animation. You can see the demo here:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-an-image-rotator-in-flash-using-xml-and-actionscript-3-0/

As you can see, there's a transparent info panel below.
Here's the code how it is being created:

```
private var infoPanel:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var titleField:TextField = new TextField();
private var description:TextField = new TextField();

private function createInfoPanel():void
{
infoPanel.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.5);
infoPanel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 967, 138);
infoPanel.graphics.endFill();

titleField.text = xml.children()[infoCounter]. @ title;
titleField.x = 50;
titleField.y = 25;

description.text = xml.children()[infoCounter]. @ description;
description.x = 52;
description.y = 51;

infoPanel.y = 300;

infoPanel.addChild(titleField);
infoPanel.addChild(description);

addChild(infoPanel);
}
```

When I create it like this, there is no animation, it is static and only text is changing.

Here's what I want to do:
When it is being created,
come to screen from below,
sliding to top,
then text appear,
before the image changes, text disappear
than the panel slides down then image changes.

How can I implement this?
Thanks.

P.S. You can see the whole code in the link.

edit: feel free to take a look at my source files.
https://rapidshare.com/files/2794372874/Src.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an animation with code is usually achieved with tweening engine. Here is one: [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).

So if you want that `infoPanel` comes from below:

```
infoPanel.y = 400; //position from where animation begins; x stays the same
TweenLite.to(infoPanel, 1.2 /* seconds */, {y:300});
```

Then you could use delay property to start another animation after a certain delay:

```
description.alpha = 0;
TweenLite.to(description, 0.5, {alpha: 1, delay: 1.2});
```

Also don't forget to `import com.greensock.*;` at the beginning of the class.

Comment: hi Miha, thanks for the answer. waited for an answer, before yours, I created a new layer with a movieclip instead. so I don't need to animate the panel anymore. but now I have 2 problems, could you take a look if you can? http://forums.adobe.com/message/4274512#4274512

Comment: Hi, I added a comment to your last question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making banner ads I wouldn't use external Tween libraries as they will push the weight of your creative over IAB standards (40kb - 50kb)

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Test extends Sprite
{
    private var imageTween:Array = [];
    private var infoPanel:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Test()
    {
        imageTween.push(new Tween(infoPanel, 'y', Regular.easeIn, 0, 300, .7, true);
        imageTween[imageTween.length-1].addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, removeTween);
    }
    private function removeTween(e:TweenEvent):void
    {
        e.target.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, removeTween);
        imageTween = [];
    }
}
```

You just have to remember to have your animations in a place where the garbage collector can't get them (in an array), otherwise they'll be swept away before they finish :(

Comment: I think you are right. Already my banner is slow at first time opening. Anyway, I've created a new layer with loading txt file. Now it's working good. Only problem is that browser doesn't refresh XML and TXT sources unless I clear the history. But I guess that's another issue.

Comment: write your XML with PHP using these header: <?php
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo '<creative><constants layout="3"></constants></creative>';

Comment: what about file extension? will it be an xml file php code included? that's it? I'm asking because I need to refresh txt files, too.

Comment: php extension - the file outputs xml normally

Comment: hi again, thanks for the help. it works great with your way. with txt files, i used meanless querystring. however, i have this issue: my hosting does not allow php, it's windows hosting, so i load external php file. do you think i can do this with aspx or js instead of php?